# LyX: Adding External PDF in Hebrew File

Tags: lyx, external-files, hebrew

I am trying to add an external pdf file in my document written in LyX, using the Hebrew Article document class. Following suggestions from other questions, I tried to use the "pdfpages" package but I'm struggling with it. When trying to compile the pdf (pdflatex specifically) I get the error message:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex: 1 unmatched \pdfsave after page shipout
```

I have found no information on this specific error message or its relation to the "pdfpages" package. Can anyone shed some light on the problem?

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example? See here for more information: http://http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might arise when importing a file that was prepared in one language into a file that was prepared in another (for instance, inserting an english document into a hebrew one).

It is easily solved by switching language before the insert, simply add in ERT `\selectlanguage{english}` before the insert.

Of course if you're inserting a hebrew file it would become `\selectlanguage{hebrew}`